# Cannot display returned property values from MVC controller with .ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

On the click event of a search button I'm sending the search text as parameter to a method on the controller. That method will return back a tool object that has properties like Name and Price in it.  I can see the method is returning the tool object to the javascript and I can see the object is of tool type in the javascript but I cannot get the properties out of this object.  How can I do something like this: `document.getElementById('QSPrice').value = data.Price`

VB.net

```
  Function TestQuickSearch(ByVal searchItem As String) As Tool

    Dim QSVM As Model.SearchViewModel = New Model.SearchViewModel()
    Dim returnedItem = QSVM.GetToolByItemNum(searchItem)

    Return returnedItem
End Function
```

JavaScript

```
$("#btnQuickSearch").live("click", function (e) {
        var searchText =  document.getElementById('txtQuickSearch').value

        if(searchText.length !== 0) {
            var Url = '@Url.Content("~/Route/QuickSearch")';

            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                async: 'false',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {searchItem: searchText},
                success: function (data) {                        

                    alert(data.Price);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //Show Message
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Show Message

        }
    });
```

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` print?

Comment: I don't know what window it prints that to in visual studio.

Comment: Look it in the browser

Comment: We're talking javascript here, client-side, use console.log() to log stuff in the browser's console (F12)

Comment: It printed the data Entity name which is correct.

Comment: And console.log(data.Price) is undefined.

Comment: Please include in your question, how does `returnedItem` look like, and also, how do you serialize it for the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended doing.

> vb.net Code

```
Function QuickSearch(ByVal searchItem As String) As JsonResult

    Dim QSVM As BusinessModel.QuickSearchViewModel = New BusinessModel.QuickSearchViewModel()
    Dim returnedItem = QSVM.GetToolItemByItemNum(searchItem)

    Return Json(New With {Key .results = returnedItem}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

> JavaScript Code

```
 $("#btnQuickSearch").live("click", function (e) {
        var searchText =  document.getElementById('txtQuickSearch').value

        if(searchText.length !== 0) {
            var Url = '@Url.Content("~/Route/QuickSearch")';

            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                async: 'false',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {searchItem: searchText},
                success: function (results) {                        
                    for (var key in results) {
                        if(results[key] !== null){
                            var obj = results[key];
                            for (var prop in obj) {
                                if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                                    switch(prop) {
                                        case "Price":
                                            document.getElementById('QSPrice').value = obj[prop];
                                            break;
                                        case "Description":
                                            document.getElementById('QSDescription').value = obj[prop];
                                            break;
                                        case "Class":
                                            document.getElementById('QSClass').value = obj[prop];
                                            break;
                                        case "QtyOnHand":
                                            document.getElementById('QSQty').value = obj[prop];
                                            break;
                                        case "TakeOrderF":
                                            var boolValue;
                                            if(obj[prop] == true){
                                                boolValue = "Yes";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                boolValue = "No";
                                            }
                                            document.getElementById('QSCanOrder').value = boolValue;
                                            break;
                                        case "Warranty":
                                            document.getElementById('QSWarranty').value = obj[prop];
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            showMessage("Item Not Found.");
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    showMessage("Item Not Found/json error.");
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Show Message
            showMessage("Item Not Found.");
        }
    });
```